# res.redirect is not a function error in nextjs

Tags: next.js, next.js13, phonepe

I am trying to do some validation at server side and use that result to redirect user to external payment provider but it is showing me error.

```
TypeError: res.redirect is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/payments/phonepe/route.ts:51:24)
```

My frontend page is

```
'use client';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { create } from 'domain';
import React from 'react';
// import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

function page() {
  async function createpayment() {
    await fetch(`/api/payments/phonepe`, {
      method: 'POST',
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={createpayment}>Checkout</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default page;
```

and my route.tsx is below and my payment is initiated but I am not being redirected to the payment gateway website which I want. Plus I don't want to do axios request in the client side as that would expose my merchant key and secret which are needed for payment.
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
import axios from 'axios';

type ResponseData = {
  message: string;
};

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>
) {
  try {
    console.log('initiated');
    const merchantTransactionId = req.body.transactionId;
    const data = {
      merchantId: process.env.PHONEPE_MERCHANT_ID,
      merchantTransactionId: 'merchantTransactionId',
      merchantUserId: 'req.body.MUID',
      name: 'req.body.name',
      amount: 23 * 100,
      redirectUrl: `http://localhost:5000/api/status/${merchantTransactionId}`,
      redirectMode: 'POST',
      mobileNumber: '90000000000',
      paymentInstrument: {
        type: 'PAY_PAGE',
      },
    };
    const payload = JSON.stringify(data);
    const payloadMain = Buffer.from(payload).toString('base64');
    const keyIndex = process.env.PHONEPE_KEY_INDEX;
    const string = payloadMain + '/pg/v1/pay' + process.env.PHONEPE_SALT_KEY;
    const sha256 = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(string).digest('hex');
    const checksum = sha256 + '###' + keyIndex;

    // const prod_URL = 'https://api.phonepe.com/apis/hermes/pg/v1/pay';
    const prod_URL = 'https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/hermes/pg/v1/pay';

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: prod_URL,
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-VERIFY': checksum,
      },
      data: {
        request: payloadMain,
      },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        // return res.redirect(
        //   response.data.data.instrumentResponse.redirectInfo.url
        // );
        return res.writeHead(301, {
          Location: response.data.data.instrumentResponse.redirectInfo.url,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "error.message || 'Internal Server Error'",
      //   success: false,
    });
  }
}

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Answer (score 0):

In the App Router API handlers (`/app/api/**/route.ts`) we don't have access to `res` object as a 2nd argument. Instead, we use the constructor `NextResponse` (or just `Response` in edge runtime) to make a response for the user.

For redirection, we have 2 ways:

###### 1. redirect function from `next/navigation`

```js
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
 
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  // this redirect function throws a custom error under the hood.
  // therefore, you don't need to return anything after using it.
  // the API handler will automatically exit and redirect the user.
  // it is also type-friendly (its return type is `never`)
  redirect('https://nextjs.org/')
}
```

more information from the official documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#redirects

###### 2. redirect method from `NextResponse`

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/new', request.url))
```

more information from the official documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#redirect

Comment: won't be able to pass payload if I use nextReponse.redirect() and first is throwing cors error.

Comment: @Rishabh What do you mean by passing payload? where do you want to pass it?